# cmake c++ library with opencv addexternal

Tags: opencv, cmake, linker

I would like to build a C++ library using cmake.
The library would require a **on-the-fly opencv download and build** then this library will be used in an other cmake project as a library.

The project structure is like that:

```
template_matching_project
    |
    |-- build
    |-- template_matching_project
    |              |
    |              |-- template_matching_library
    |                              |
    |                              | -- src
    |                              | -- include
    |                              | -- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- main.cpp
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
```

The template_matching_library performs some image processing using opencv, there is the content of its cmake file in *template_matching_project/template_matching_library/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(template_matching)

# third party
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/3rdparty)
set(EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Download)

# OpenCV
ExternalProject_Add(opencv-contrib
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
  GIT_TAG e6f32c6
  SOURCE_DIR "${EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}/opencv-contrib"
  CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
  BUILD_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Add(opencv
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
  GIT_TAG 01b2c5a
  SOURCE_DIR "${EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}/opencv"
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
     ...
)
add_dependencies(opencv opencv-contrib)

# set source directories
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR source)
set(INCLUDE_DIR include)

# set source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${INCLUDE_DIR}/*)

# build library
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv/lib)

include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv/include/opencv4)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} opencv)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIR})
```

The template_matching_library is correctly build with this cmake, but the build of the `main.cpp` executable fails

Here is the template_matching_project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

project(markers)

# include library
add_subdirectory(template_matching_library)
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/3rdparty)
include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv/include/opencv4)

# add file to compile
set(SRCS main.cpp)

# add executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})

# add dependencies
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} template_matching)
```

Then trying the build with the convetional

```
cd build
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
make
```

I have the following error

```
[ 95%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/markers.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable markers
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any suggestion to solve my problem? Should I change one/both of those CMakeLists.txt.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your target `markers` doesn't know **where** to find these OpenCV libraries. You told the `template_matching` target where to find them using [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html), but not `markers`. You could try adding this call to the `template_matching_project/CMakeLists.txt` file also. Please note, the use of `link_directories()` is *discouraged*...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, indeed ```link_directories``` should be avoid.
I managed to have work with this solution in case it may be useful for someone else or maybe other suggestions could arise

Answer (score 1):

I have it worked with those two CMakeLists.txt, if some have any suggestions or better solution.

template_matching_project/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(markers)

add_subdirectory(template_matching_library)
set(SRCS main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} template_matching ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

template_matching_project/template_matching_library/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(template_matching)

# third party
include(ExternalProject)
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/3rdparty)
set(EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Download)

# OpenCV
ExternalProject_Add(opencv-contrib
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
  GIT_TAG e6f32c6
  SOURCE_DIR "${EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}/opencv-contrib"
  ...
)

ExternalProject_Add(opencv
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
  GIT_TAG 01b2c5a
  SOURCE_DIR "${EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}/opencv"
  CMAKE_ARGS
    -DBUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
    ...
    -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH:PATH=${EXTERNAL_DOWNLOAD_LOCATION}/opencv-contrib/modules
)
add_dependencies(opencv opencv-contrib)
set(OpenCV_DIR ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv/lib/cmake/opencv4)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS ${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv)

# set source directories
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR source)
set(INCLUDE_DIR include)

# set source files
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS ${INCLUDE_DIR}/*)

# build library
include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/opencv/include/opencv4)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} opencv)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Nevertheless, using my two CMakeLists.txt, I do have to run twice cmake and make commands, unless I have a links errors with opencv, like the following:

```
cd build
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles
make 
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles
make
```

Is there a way to have work with a single run cmake/make?

I try some `FetchContent` but was not able to make it worked. My cmake version is 3.5.1